# Mongoose updateMany based on result of previous query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have two collections `energyOffers` and `energyOfferLogs`. When a user deactivated their account I'm looking for all the remaining active energyOffers where the entity of the user is in the `assignees` array, not in the `declinedEntities` array and the `offerValidTill` date is less than the current timestamp.

```
const [energyOffers] = await EnergyOffer.find([{ 
    'assignees.id': entityID, 
    declinedEntities: { 
        $ne: leadID 
    },
    offerValidTill: { $gt: Date.now() }
}], { session });
```

Based on these energyOffers I need to update the corresponding `energyOfferLogs`. I can find these with `{ entityID: entityID, 'offer.offerID': offer._id }` but how can I look for all these offers in the same query?

If I loop through the `energyOffers` I will have to perform multiple updates while my guess is that this can be done in one `updateMany`. I was looking into the `$lookup` aggregate operator (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) but it seems that the EnergyOffer find query is too complex to perform in this.

```
await EnergyOfferLog.updateMany({ ??? }, {
    $set: {
        'offer.action': 'declined',
        'offer.action_date': Math.floor(Date.now()),
        'offer.action_user': user.first_name,
        'offer.action_user_id': userID
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with one query only, it is not complex. You can use `$lookup` with a pipeline for this:

1. Start with your `$match` query on the `energyOffers` collection
2. Use '$lookup`to get the matching`energyOfferLogs`
3. Clean the pipeline to contain only the `energyOfferLogs` docs
4. Perform the `$set`
5. Use `$merge` to save it back to `energyOfferLogs` collection

```
db.energyOffers.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      "assignees.id": entityID,
      declinedEntities: {$ne: leadID},
      offerValidTill: {$gt: Date.now()}
    }
  },
  {$lookup: {
      from: "energyOfferLogs",
      let: {offerId: "$_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $and: [
              {entityID: entityID},
              {$expr: {$eq: ["$offer.offerID", "$$offerId"]}}
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "energyOfferLogs"
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$energyOfferLogs"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$energyOfferLogs"}},
  {$set: {
      "offer.action": "declined",
      "offer.action_date": Math.floor(Date.now()),
      "offer.action_user": user.first_name,
      "offer.action_user_id": userID
    }
  },
  {$merge: {into: "$energyOfferLogs"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aQlLFC3cKxT)

- Answer was updated according to a remark by @Alex_Blex

Comment: I'd use $unwind instead of `{$project: {energyOfferLogs: {$first: "$energyOfferLogs"}}}`.

Comment: why do prefer `$unwind` over `$first`?

Comment: what if there are more than 1 log entry per offer?

Comment: I agree and updated the answer accordingly. Nice catch

Answer (score 3):

Get all offer ids from the first query, e.g.

```
let ids = energyOffers.map(o => o._id)
```

Use [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to match logs for all matching offers:

```
await EnergyOfferLog.updateMany({ entityID: entityID, 'offer.offerID': {$in: ids} }, {
    $set: {
        'offer.action': 'declined',
        'offer.action_date': Math.floor(Date.now()),
        'offer.action_user': user.first_name,
        'offer.action_user_id': userID
    }
});
```